# Shell script error on slackware based Linux OS

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that works on Ubuntu and provides me an output as I desire. When I test the same on a slackware linux version, my script fails.

The script fails at:

```
dialog --title "Test" --gauge "Copying file." 6 100 < <(
    rsync -a --progress test.tar.gz /media/sda1 | 
    unbuffer -p grep -o "[0-9]*%" | 
    unbuffer -p cut -f1 -d '%'  
    )
```

The error is:

```
Syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

What could be different between the two operating systems that the script fails to execute?
The script executes successfully if I get rid of the dialog command and the brackets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update below]

The `< <( ... )` notation is unique for `bash` and `zsh`.  The syntax error is a clear sign it is not recognised by the slackware shell.

Either slackware does not use bash, or its version of bash is too old for this feature.
Check the value of $BASH_VERSION on both platforms.

A possible alternative for

```
cat < <(
    ...
    ...
)
```

could be:

```
cat <<< "$(
    ...
    ...
)"
```

This will work in bash, ksh93, and zsh, and has been around slightly longer.

UPDATE

Based on your feedback, I've looked at the actual pipeline you try to use here.
I believe it's your intention to use column 3 of the `--progress` output as input for the dialog graphical progress indicator.

I tried this with a directory with lots of small files.  Are you aware that this percentage indicator is per file?  With my small files, rsync gave only one update per file.  As every single file was written in one go, all percentages were equal to `100%`.

Comment: This actually fixes the problem but the cat command seems to buffer everything. Do you have a suggestion to redirect the current output to dialog? I also tried `cat -u <<< "$( ...)"`. This does not seem to empty the buffer rapidly

Comment: It is normal for unix processes to buffer i/o.  And I'm not familiar with `dialog`.  Let me check...

Comment: Aha... I see what that does.  Perhaps you need a traditional pipeline for that.  `rsync ... | unbuffer ... | dialog ...`. Haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I did that. Its resetting the dialog every time and shows 0% everytime. Working on an alternative

Comment: Can you try `rsync -a --progress ${origin:?} ${destination:?} 6 100 | nawk '{ print $3 }'`?  I only get blank lines and `100%`

Comment: I am interested in transferring only one large file. I would have [used this](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2008/12/24/zenity-rsync-and-awk/) if I were transferring a large number of small files. I am commenting this based on your recent update

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are trying to run a bash script with non-bash shell. Or with older bash version.

First, try running it through bash explicitly, i.e.:

```
bash script.sh
```

You should also fix your shebang to point at bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not work out. I am actually using a similar syntax elsewhere on the same system and it worked out just fine. Weird!

Comment: Both `<` are necessary; the first is the standard input redirection operator; the second introduces the process substitution from which standard input is being redirected.

Comment: @chepner Yes both the `<` are necessary. It is so strange and I do not understand whats going on

Comment: What are the bash versions on the two systems?

Comment: @chepner: You are right, thanks for forcing me to lookup that `info bash` and seeing it myself ;). I removed that from the post since it seems that there is no <del/> thingie here.

Comment: @MichałGórny Yes there was a bash version mismatch. I am trying to fix the problem now